# Why is document.remove() not working in Mongoose, Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Problem: I try to **delete a document from the database using document.remove()** in the following codes, but *it does not remove this document from database*. I am confident remove() is called because the pre hook I set up for 'remove' is called.

```
// Delete - delete a player and update the team
router.delete("/:player_id", function(req, res) {
    Player.findById(req.params.player_id, function(err, foundPlayer) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.flash("error", "Player you want to delete is NOT FOUND!");
            res.redirect("back");
            return;
        }
        foundPlayer.remove(function(err, removedPlayer) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log(removedPlayer); // prints null
            }
        }); // <<<<<<<<<<<
        res.redirect("back");
    });
});
```

I then use **model.findByIdAndRemove()** in the following codes, and it worked.

```
// Delete - delete a player and update the team
router.delete("/:player_id", function(req, res) {
    Player.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.player_id, function(err, foundPlayer) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.flash("error", "Player you want to delete is NOT FOUND!");
            res.redirect("back");
            return;
        }
        res.redirect("back");
    });
});
```

I have two Schemas:

```
var TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    players: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: "Player"
        }
    ],
});

var PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    team: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Team"
    }
});
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have used the `.remove()` on the foundPlayer which was returned by the `findByID` . You should use the remove directly on the model from which you are trying to remove the document. For eg. The following would work -

```
Player.remove({_id:req.params.player_id},function(err, foundPlayer){
    if(!err)
        console.log(foundPlayer);
});
```

If the player with given `_id` has been found you will get something logged onto the console like this -

```
deleted
{ n: 1, ok: 1, deletedCount: 1 }
```

---

### **NOTE :**

Trying to use `remove()` will probably give you an warning saying -

```
DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
```

So, you must use deleteOne or deleteMany instead according to your requirement. So your code should be like this -

```
Player.deleteOne({_id:req.params.player_id},function(err, foundPlayer){
    if(!err)
        console.log(foundPlayer);
});
```

You can also choose to use the following if you want to use the `foundPlayer`doucment itself to be used in callback -

- `findOneAndDelete()` / `findByIdAndDelete()` : Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback. Executes immediately if callback is passed, else a Query object is returned.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

remove() has been deprecated,
 try this

```
Player.deleteOne(req.params.player_id,function(err, removedPlayer) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log(removedPlayer); // prints null
            }
        }); // <<<<<<<<<<<
```